# Há um meio de "espelhar" propriedades de um objeto em outro?

Tags: javascript, orientação-a-objetos

Digamos que eu queira fazer uma função tipo `debugText(obj)`, essa função toma um objeto como parametro e mostra uma propiedade dele na tela, como as debug screens de jogos.

Algo como:

```
function debugText(link,prop) {

  this.TextObject = new Engine.Utils.Text()

  this.link = link
  this.prop = prop

  this.update = function () {
    this.TextObject.setText( this.link[this.prop] )
  }

}
```

Em uso:

```
var texto1 = new debugText(Player,"speedX")
var texto2 = new debugText(Missle,"positionY")
```

Funciona muito bem para estes dois exemplos e quando eu preciso saber de outras coisas na hora de testar o codigo, mais se eu quiser acessar algo tipo:

`Player.skin.currentAnimation.frame.frameInfo.index`?

Eu poderia adicionar mais parametros a função e depois ver quantos deles estão sendo usados e criar a `this.update` baseado nisso.

Porém essa função sempre estará limitada há um numero fixo de propiedades e mesmo que eu nunca vá usar mais de 5 eu ainda não gostei de como essa função funciona:
http://pastebin.com/WWT6VYE5

**EDIT**

A questão é: tem um meio correto de "espelhar" as propiedades de um objeto ou de atualiza-las com uma *function call* independente de quantos niveis de profundidade de `Object.prop1.prop2.pro3...` que tiver que atualizar?

Para vocês terem ideia de quantas formas já pensei em como fazer isto essa é a ultima

`debugText(Player.skin.currentAnimation.frame.frameInfo,"index")`

Este tambem funciona MAS realmente é certo passar um objeto com as propiedades e passar só a ultima propiedade como string apenas para usar as *computed property names* para acessar este valor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma sugestão:

```
var obj = {
    foo: 12345,
    bar: {
        teste: {
            aninhado: {
                chave: 6789
            }
        }
    }
};

function mostrarProps(obj, props) {
    var valores = props.map(function(prop) {
        if (typeof prop == 'string') return obj[prop];
        // else...
        var key, val = obj;
        while (key = prop.shift()){
            val = val[key];
        }
        return val;
    });
    document.body.innerHTML = valores.join('<br>');
}

mostrarProps(obj, ['foo', ['bar', 'teste', 'aninhado', 'chave']]);
```

A ideia é ter uma função que aceita uma array de propriedades a procurar. Nessa array podes ter _String_s para aceder diretamente a propriedades num primeiro nível, ou uma array com "o caminho" a percorrer até chegar ao valor que queres.

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ekk2772e/

#### Contudo:

acho que seria mais simples usares `console.log()` para saber os valores de objetos caso seja para debug, ou até o `JSON.stringify()` que transforma o objeto numa string e assim cria uma imagem estática de como o objeto estava numa dada altura.

Comment: Eu não posso usar o console.log() porque as vezes eu tenho que mostrar mais de 5 coisas com valores atualizados uma vez por frame e isso alem de flodar o conosole, acaba lagando um pouco. Agora o JSON.stringfy realmente pode me ajudar neste caso. Valeu cara, iria demorar muito pensar nisso.